# iPhone app startup zoom effect

Tags: iphone, startup, zooming, effect

I've noticed when starting apps on the iPhone, they first appear as small windows gradually getting bigger and bigger, until filling the entire screen. These small windows look like the applications. However, when running my applications on my iPhone, the zooming windows are always black. Why is that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add a picture to your project, name it Default.png, with the dimensions 320x480, and that will cause it to show when you start up the application.

http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/defaultpng-the-secret-of-the-load-screen.html

Comment: Does it matter if its 320x480, or 480x320?

Comment: BTW, the Screenshots tab for your physical device in Xcode's Organizer window has an option to set a specific screenshot as the Default.png file in your project.

Answer (score 3):

It's because they are using [a launch image](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW5). It's scaled to look like a window filling the screen.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a `Default.png` file in your application bundle. See [Application Icon and Launch Images](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ApplicationEnvironment/ApplicationEnvironment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW16):

> The file for the application’s launch image is named `Default.png`. This image should closely resemble the application’s initial user interface; the system displays the launch image before an application is ready to display its user interface, giving users the impression of a quick launch. The launch image should also be a PNG image file, located in the top level of the application bundle. If the application is launched through a URL, the system looks for a launch image named `Default-scheme.png`, where scheme is the scheme of the URL. If that file is not present, it chooses `Default.png` instead.